# CefSharp - Formatting

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am trying to use CefSharp as a pretty basic HTML Browser for an application that I am making. It's going to be used to browse a website that is used at the company I work for. However, when looking at the website in Chrome vs CefSharp it looks like the formatting is off.

CfeSharp
[image]
Chrome
[image]

It's kind of hard to tell, but if you have both of the image open and swap between the two of them you can notice how "Reporting" is actually a different Font or something. I have tried searching around to see if there is a way to change the formatting or something, but the only thing I have found is to make sure the "locales" folder is there with all the different *.pak files. Is there something that I am missing? While it doesn't look to bad on this page, other pages are much worst and look more bloated because of the difference. I can't really show the other pages unfortunately.

Comment: If you call __.ShowDevTools()__ on your ChromiumWebBrowser instance and refresh the page, does the Console or Network tabs show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be due to pak files missing or the path of pak files not configured properly.
Provide the path of en-us.pak file in CefSettings:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.LocalesDirPath = <path>;
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

This worked for me.